# Using another GPS Android over Bluetooth (Android to Android device)

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps

In this case I have Android device A and Android device B.
In my project I want to make my apps so that they can change the type of GPS Android A to GPS Android B over Bluetooth.

So when I disable the GPS or Internet, or both of them in Android A, Bluetooth A will connect to another device (Android B) and use Android device B's GPS over Bluetooth in Android device A.

Is this possible to do? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question! so I have to give you a general answer...

It is possible, you have to develop a **client/server** application which can communicate and send data over BlueTooth.

The server application(**Device B**) must be able to get GPS data and share it over BlueTooth and client application(**Device A**) must be able to connect over BlueTooth and received GPS data from device B and use it on device A.

The point is it would never be like the hardware data that is being used with all applications on your device and you can use this data on your client application.

Comment: is the code too complex ? both of them ? client and server i mean

Comment: It depends on your skills! but it is not impossible. give it a shot ;)

Comment: I know my skill maybe still under pro but i sure i pass the beginner :). My client want to use third party gps when gps phone is disabled over bluetooth. is the apps will more slow process if i add this feature ? or maybe i should use third party apps for this ? what will you do if you in this case ? for good result. thanks mohsen :)

Comment: Third party GPS devices usually include SDK for developers with a documentation which could help you with your app development.